# Can I configure dpkg to launch kdiff when there's a conflict with a config file update?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

We've all seen it...

```
Configuration file 'blah/blah/blah.conf'
==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
 What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
   Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
   N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
     D     : show the differences between the versions
     Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
The default action is to keep your current version.
```

Sometimes, the differences are rather extensive. I've modded my working config, but I also want to see what config options have changed (and also get the latest comments from the latest stock config file). So, I can't just pick from the two... I want to *merge*.

I user KDiff3 for this. But it's tedious to have to open another terminal window and copy/paste the names of the *existing* config file and the *dpkg-new* version.

I know that I can set env variables like PAGER and EDITOR and programs like crontab will dutifully use my preferred editor and pager. **Is there a way to tell dpkg to use a certain program for "show the differences" so that it launches KDiff3 which will let me merge things into my working config file?**

Answer (score 0):

I bet `D` uses hard coded `diff | pager`, i.e. read-only mode just to show the differences. Then choosing `Y` or `N` keeps or replaces the whole file. There is no interactive merge possibility and you cannot overload it. Partially for that purpose is the `Z`, but you will have to do it the way you did it.

There are md5sums of all files in the `.deb` so I guess this is the reason why there isn't option like this, because the installation of the package would fail if the md5 did not match.